# Can’t get S3 trigger Event value from Lambda ECR image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am using S3, Lambda and ECR. Lambda function is deployed with ECR image. And Lambda function gets triggered by upload to the S3 bucket.

I want to get S3 trigger Event data (to see uploaded filename) from my `entrypoint.sh` file. Currently I get empty value without errors/warnings.

My code is written in `/bin/bash` script. All files are in root folder.

These are things I tried or checked:

- S3 bucket, Lambda function and ECR are deployed on the same AWS server center.
- My Lambda function has PUT and GET permissions to the S3 bucket.
- When I upload to the S3 bucket, it triggers Lambda function as expected.
- Dockerfile `WORKDIR` is set to `/var/task` and copied files there.
- My Lambda function starts and finishes (no problem with initialization).
- I look through the logs in CloudWatch and don’t see any error.
- I’ve increased timeout duration and memory of the Lambda function but no difference.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/qiime2/core:2023.2

RUN pip install -U --no-cache-dir awscli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/classifier/ \
  && curl -L https://data.qiime2.org/2023.2/common/silva-138-99-515-806-nb-classifier.qza -o /tmp/classifier/silva-138-99-515-806-nb-classifier.qza

COPY . /var/task

WORKDIR /var/task

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

`entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract the S3 event data from the environment variable
read input_data
echo "input_data $input_data"

echo "AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY: ${AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY}"
echo "AWS_EVENT: ${AWS_EVENT}"
echo "AWS_EVENT_DATA $AWS_EVENT_DATA"
echo "AWS_EVENT_DATA $test"
```

Comment: Does the docker image `quay.io/qiime2/core:2023.2` implement the AWS Lambda runtime interface? It certainly doesn't appear to. AWS Lambda is not a generic container runtime. Lambda can only run containers that implement the AWS Lambda runtime interface.